# Normal command map, tab is interpreted as literal

Tags: vim

When I make a `.vimrc` entry,

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>c :colorscheme <tab>
```

The `tab` is applied if I understand the terminalogy, as a literal, that is, upon typing `,c`, I get in Vim command line,

```
:colorscheme ^I
```

I tried to internet the search terms, but mostly I get results about remapping Vim Tabs; the closest I found was somebody putting quotes around their `<tab>`, but I think that is for a different desired outcome.

I also have this, which is why I want the `tab` in my shortcut,

```
set wildmenu
set wildmode=longest:list,full
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need the `'wildcharm'` option:

```
set wildcharm=<C-z>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>c :colorscheme <C-z>
```

See `:help 'wildcharm'`.

As a side note, I use that option with great effect for switching buffers:

```
nnoremap <leader>b :buffer <C-z><S-Tab>
```

and a file-opening variant would be just as easy and just as useful:

```
nnoremap <leader>e :edit <C-z><S-Tab>
```

Comment: Maybe use `<c-d>` instead of tab. `nnoremap <silent> <leader>c : colorscheme <c-d>``

Comment: If I internet search for `wildcharm`...  hindsight is 20/20. @romaini can I ask what your `wildmode` is set to? For mine, to get what I think is your desired effect, I need two tabs, that is, `<C-z><C-z><S-Tab>`. I'm assuming you're trying to get the prompt empty, so that you can type some characters to take advantage of narrowing.

Comment: @BradyTrainor, yes that's exactly the purpose of that mapping. I have `set wildmode=list:full`.

Comment: @romainl, (pardon typo) aha, I hadn't even gotten around to picking up on the commas in `wildmode` setting syntax. <reading `:h wildmode`... >.